# Hamiltonian for closed strings

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory

I am reading GSW volume 1 and it says in chapter 2 that the Hamiltonian for closed strings turn out to be $$ H = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (\alpha_{-n}.\alpha_{n} + \tilde{\alpha}_{-n}\cot \tilde{\alpha}_{n})\;.$$  I tried to calculate it and I got twice of this i.e.  $$ H =  \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (\alpha_{-n}.\alpha_{n} + \tilde{\alpha}_{-n}.\tilde{\alpha}_{n})\;.$$ I also calculated it in terms of virasoro modes and got $H = 2 (L_0 + \tilde{L_0}) $ as opposed to $H =  (L_0 + \tilde{L_0}) $ mentioned in GSW and here I just used the definitions of $ H $,  $L_0$ and $\tilde{L_0} $ without using $\alpha$ anywhere. I have attached the images of my calculation. Could somebody please see it and tell me what mistake I might be doing?

[image]
[image]
(click to enlarge)

Comment: Hi, Himanshu! Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange!! Please note that this is not a homework-helping site. For more guidance, please check our [meta site](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714).

Comment: Hi Himanshu Khanchandani. Linking to private clouds, dropbox, etc, is for various reasons not acceptable on SE, cf. [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11400/2451) meta post.